# Python - RGB Tuples

Tags: python

I have currently a tuple of:

```
('(102,117,108)', '(108,32,116)', '(101,120,116)', '(32,105,115)', '(32,103,111)', '(111,100,32)')
```

How would I convert it to:

```
((102,117,108), (108,32,116), (101,120,116), (32,105,115), (32,103,111), (111,100,32))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> t = ('(102,117,108)', '(108,32,116)', '(101,120,116)', '(32,105,115)', '(32,103,111)', '(111,100,32)')
>>> tuple(map(literal_eval, t))
((102, 117, 108), (108, 32, 116), (101, 120, 116), (32, 105, 115), (32, 103, 111), (111, 100, 32))
```

> **literal_eval(node_or_string)**
>       Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>       expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
>       Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
>       and None.